# Graficar recta punto por punto con un pequeño retardo en Canvas android

Tags: android, hilos, canvas

Necesito hacer una pequeña animación para graficar una recta punto por punto, de tal forma que la recta salga de un extremo de la pantalla y vaya incrementando poco a poco hasta llegar al otro lado.

Ya dibuje las líneas rectas en el canvas.

Traté de utilizar `Thread.sleep(millis)`, pero si lo hago en el `MainUI thread` la aplicación se pausa indefinidamente hasta que el propio sistema decide terminar la actividad.

He investigado algunas otra alternativas tales como `AsyncTask`, `Handlers`, `CountdownTimer`. Pero cuando refactorizo mi código para adaptarlo surge un nuevo problema. De acuerdo a lo que he investigado, no puedo dibujar en el canvas desde un hilo en segundo plano. La aplicación se ejecuta correctamente sin lanzar ninguna excepción, y el código que se encarga de dibujar los puntos sí se ejecuta, ya que puedo observar en el `log` los mensajes que envío.

Tengo muy poca experiencia trabajando con hilos.
Hay alguna forma o sugerencia que sea más apropiada para hacer esto?

Algún tema en específico para investigar?

Comment: Estaría bueno si podés poner el código que tenés actualmente, así es más facíl ayudarte